# Which JDBC jar should I use with java 1.5.0_16 and PostgreSQL 8.3.5?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Which JDBC jar should I use with java 1.5.0_16 and PostgreSQL 8.3.5?

Answer (score 1):

Are you having an issue with the standard postgresql JDBC driver? I'm not using it right now, but I have in the past and it worked fine: http://jdbc.postgresql.org/

Answer (score 1):

jdbc4 can only be used with java 1.6+ so you'll want 8.3-XYZ.jdbc3.